# Chart.js How should I do to make vertical dotted line

Tags: javascript, html, graph, chart.js

I'm currently practicing making a graph using Chart.js.
The problem is I want to make a graph that looks as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVk3f.png)

I was able to make the horizontal dotted line, but I have no idea what to do for the vertical dotted line.
The code I wrote until now is as below:

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',

    data: {
        labels: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
            data: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
        },{
            label: 'My First dataset2',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
            data: [60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
        },{
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            data: [30, 30, 30, 30],
            borderDash: [10, 5]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
        title:{
            display: true,
            text: 'Demand and Supply'
        },
        legend:{
            display: false
        }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have an external example, i hope this help you!

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/dbyze2ga/257][1]
```